# I am finding it/ I find it difficult to understand English

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, stative-verbs

> **I am  finding it dificult to understand English**
>
> **I find it difficul  to understand English**
>
> **When the power broke down, I found it difficult to feel the switch.So my daughter helped me**
>
> **When the power broke down, I was finding it difficult to feel the switch.So my daughter helped me**

What is the difference between these two sets of sentences if they are grammatically correct?

Comment: Is your question about the contexts in which _I am finding it difficult_ is the better choice? Or are you asking the much trickier question about what constitutes _standard English_?

Comment: I think  I am finding it is not good English.If it is., it is better to discard grammar books and  dictionaries

Comment: It certainly is good English. For example: _I'm finding it difficult now that my children have left home_. In this context it is a better choice than _I find it ..._.

Comment: Why have the entries not given in grammar books and dictionaries.Ofcourse nonnative speakers may use themBut native speakers are also using them violating   usage and grammar.

Comment: In the context I exemplified _find_ is an expression of feeling. Swan in _Practical English Grammar_ (p469) says: "_Verbs that refer to physical feelings (e.g. feel, hurt, ache) can often be used in simple or progressive tenses without much difference in meaning_". Dictionaries are not particularly good grammar resources, and English grammar is far too complex for a pedagogic grammar to cover it all. Not even massive descriptive grammars such as Quirk's or Huddlestone & Pullum's can do that.

Comment: Find  is  not in the list.

Comment: I think you'll have to wait for an answer from someone who has more time than me.

Comment: In fact, we cannot develop proficiency in a language by learning and memorizing grammar rules (or vocabulary items). The rules are too abstract, too complex, and too many to memorize and then apply consciously. Your mental representation of language is developed unconsciously through processes that occur when you understand messages in English for their extra-linguistic meaning. Studying descriptive grammar can be fun if one is genuinely interested in it. And it can be useful. But not for developing proficiency or literacy. To do that, focus on reading or hearing things that you can understand

Comment: well enough so that you are able to keep your mind on the messages, not the form of the language. That is how we learn our native languages, and our brains are very powerful at doing it, if we don't interfere with its natural processes. That is why native speakers so often "just know" what's standard or natural, but cannot articulate the reasons why, or when not, why not. My advice is to take some time and think about how interested you are in grammar for its own sake. If you're interested in it primarily as a tool to help you improve your proficiency, then your task should be to assess

Comment: the sources of input in English that you genuinely enjoy consuming, so you can process a lot of it. Ideally, you should be able to understand what you see or hear easily enough so that your mind can stay engaged with the meaning in a state of "flow". There's a basic pattern of progression from hearing easy things, to developing a good foundation in understanding the spoken language, to reading enjoyable things (for most people that is stories/fiction), to reading more complex texts out of academic or specialized interest. See sdkrashen.com and search for "input theory" "comprehension theory"

Comment: You are making the erroneous assumption that dictionaries and reference books contain *all* versions of acceptable language. They simply don't. They're not comprehensive enough to do so. Many examples of acceptable language are missing from dictionaries and grammar books. The OED may contain the greatest number of single words of any reference—but even it can't hope to encompass all the uses to which those individual words can be put.

Comment: As for this specific question, *I am finding it* and *I find it* are both completely natural and grammatical.

Comment: The question remains unclear. The only explicit question is *What is standard English?* Please clarify your question, or I will need to vote to have it closed.

Comment: @Jim Reynolds. +1 for referencing and summarising Stephen Krashen's comprehensible input hypothesis - in my opinion the single most important insight in SLA.

Comment: @Shoe  Yes! You might be interested in https://www.facebook.com/groups/storylistening/ That is group affiliated with the method that Krashen is currently promoting.

Comment: I've voted to close this question because it is unclear what is being asked, even after having been edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been edited to focus more narrowly on a point of usage, and I am making massive edits to my response as a result.

The progressive tenses are standard forms of a verb in English. There is no need for a dictionary to confirm that "find" can be used in a progressive tense because that is the general rule for verbs.

Nevertheless, there are certain verbs that represent states rather than actions. "Know" is an example. You either know something or you do not although we do recognize degrees of knowledge, as in

> I once knew German well, but now I remember only a bit.

The progressive tenses, however, relate to processes. The static and the progressive are inconsistent ideas. So "I am knowing German" may technically be grammatical, but it is bad English because it implies a process within a state and makes no sense. (Someone will now come up with an example where the progressive of "know" does make sense, but it will not be an example of anything common.) We can say as a rule: only in very rare cases, if ever, is it good American English to use "know" in a tense with progressive aspect.

Consider the verb "understand." Again, it describes a state that admits of degree, but it does not imply a process.

> I am understanding German

to mean

> I understand German

is not idiomatic American English. It is easier, however, to find examples where the progressive may fit with "understand" than with "know"

> It's amazing how well I am understanding German after only three days in Berlin

is idiomatic although perhaps a bit crude compared to

> It's amazing how much German I understand after only three days in Berlin.

So I am going to make up a rule

**Except for some modals, it is grammatically possible to put any verb into a tense with a progressive aspect, but, at least in American English, it is seldom idiomatic to put verbs of state into the progressive because it usually implies a subtle contradiction between a state and a process.**

Now consider "find." It is an action rather than a state so the previous rule cannot apply. Nevertheless, the verb usually has a binary nature: something is either found or lost. "Find," however, can sometimes mean "seek," "search for," or "look for," which do describe processes and are not binary. When "find" is used in that sense, the progressive can certainly be used idiomatically.

> I was finding my way in the dark when I stumbled over the cat and stubbed my toe.

It would not be idiomatic to convey that thought as

> I found my way in the dark when I stumbled over the cat and stubbed my toe.

The "when" signals an instant within a duration of time, and action across a duration calls for the progressive.

With respect to the two pairs of examples given in the edited question, I believe all four are idiomatic.

With respect to the first pair, I find the second sentence to be better because it reports on a state. I would change my mind if "learn" were substituted for "understand" because learning is a process. Given that substitution, the two sentences become equally acceptable although the second does not imply that an attempt at learning is ongoing whereas the first seems to imply that such an attempt is ongoing. That is, both sentences are acceptable but may convey slightly different meanings.

With respect to the second pair, I definitely prefer the second sentence because the sense relates to a continuing period, rather than an instant.

In conclusion, grammar should defer to meaning. This makes language difficult because simple rules cannot capture the complexities of all possible meanings, particularly not in English with its huge vocabulary and subtle verb structure.

Comment: So  I am understanding it  and  I am knowing  it  is possible  because all verbs  have  continuous  forms.

Comment: Yes, they are grammatically possible but seldom appropriate. The reason is that both verbs rarely imply a process: you know something, or you don't. We have a verb for moving between knowing and not knowing, namely "learn." You could say "At last, I am understanding calculus," which implies a process not yet ended, but it sounds odd. Better would be "At last, I am starting to understand calculus." The verb "find," however, may take place over time as in finding your way through a dark room. (more in next comment)

Comment: What is grammatically permissible does not always fit the sense. Verbs that imply a state will seldom be in a progressive form. From purely personal experience (not a formal study), Indian English seems to my American ears to overuse (misuse?) the progressive with verbs like "know" and "understand" due to the rare congruence of the binary sense of the verb and the incomplete sense of the progressive.

Comment: No. Your English does not appear to me to be Indian at all. It seems to be very much standard English though whether of the British or American variety I cannot tell. I was making a comment that quite a few Indians whom I have met and whose English is very good do use the progressive where it is inappropriate.  Consequently, I can understand why you try to avoid the progressive with "find." In nine cases out of ten, that avoidance will make no difference in the sense. But there are exceptional cases, as discussed in that other thread, where the progressive is the best choice with "find."

Comment: @JVL I am not worried about down votes, but I recognize your revised question to be legitimate and subtle. My original answer makes no sense in light of your revisions, and I have effectively given an entirely new answer.

Comment: @  Jeff Morrow.  your answer is very exhaustive, useful and educative too..It has changed my mindset too because language is not just stored in books but it survives and lives on the lips of the people who speak it. Language is as complex as God

Comment: When the question has got 1000 viewers and I have been  awarde  a dubiousbadge, the question has been closed. Besides, my question has been downvoted  twice. The entire seems to be illogical. I dont edit the question or delete it either. If you want to delete it.